# How can I turn off ESLint's no-restricted-syntax rule just for ForOfStatement?

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, for-of-loop

I am using ESLint for my ES6 program, with the AirBNB rule-set. For good and adequate reasons, I am using the `for...of` construction in my code, but ESLint objects to it, issuing a `no-restricted-syntax` error.

The documentation at http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax explains how I can specify in my `.eslint` file the set of syntax-tree nodes that it objects to: for example, if all I dislike is the `with` statement, I can use:

> "no-restricted-syntax": ["warn", "WithStatement"]

But I don't want to specify a whole set of unapproved constructions, I just want to say that I consider one such construction OK. Something conceptually similar to

> ESlint.rules['no-restricted-syntax'].removeEntry('ForOfStatement');

Is there a way to do this in the ESLint file? Or, failing that, is there at least a way to get it to tell me what its current `no-restricted-syntax` configuration is, so I can manually remove ForOfStatement from it?

Comment: a shortcut, not the best answer is using the disabling eslint rules with comments for blocks or lines or files.

Comment: If you have installed the airbnb ruleset, you can surely look it up in the respective configuration file?

Comment: Thanks, amir. I know how to tell ESLint "ignore this line" or "ignore this rule for this line": I want to be more ambitious, and teach ESLint that I consider the use of `for...of` always OK.

Comment: for those like me, who arrive here via google search, here's a good discussion about why the syntax is restricted in the first place: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but only if you use a JS config file.

In the old config system (`.eslintrc.js`):

```
const styleConfig = require('eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/style');
const [_severity, ...restrictedSyntax] = styleConfig.rules['no-restricted-syntax'];
```

In the [new flat config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) (`eslint.config.js`):

```
const compat = new FlatCompat({
  baseDirectory: __dirname,
  recommendedConfig: js.configs.recommended,
});

const airbnb = compat.extends('airbnb');
const [_severity, ...restrictedSyntax] = airbnb.find(c => c.rules?.['no-restricted-syntax']);
```

And then manipulate the `restrictedSyntax` variable as desired.

Comment: Thanks, @alexey-romanov, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 86):

#### Check existing config

Based on the current master branch, `eslint-config-airbnb` currently disables [four syntax forms](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/7152396219e290426a03e47837e53af6bcd36bbe/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/style.js#L259-L262):

1. `ForInStatement`
2. `ForOfStatement`
3. `LabeledStatement`
4. `WithStatement`

You can verify this or see if there are any differences by using ESLint's [`--print-config` CLI flag](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#print-config):

```
$ eslint --print-config file.js
```

ESLint will print out the config it would use to lint `file.js`, and you can find the config for the `no-restricted-syntax` rule there.

#### Override `no-restricted-syntax`

If you want to override Airbnb's preset, you can do so in the `rules` section of your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-restricted-syntax": ["error", "ForInStatement", "LabeledStatement", "WithStatement"]
    }
}
```

There's no way to configure the rule to use the `no-restricted-syntax` config inherited from Airbnb's preset excepting only a single syntax form.

Comment: Thanks, btmills. The bit of a puzzle I was missing was `--print-config`, which at least allows me to hand-craft an `.eslint` rule configuration that makes minimal changes to what I inherited.

Comment: It's a shame there is no way to have `.eslintrc` modify and existing rule configuration rather then replacing it; but since that's how it is, your answer tells me all there is to know. I will Accept it as soon as I find the right button!

Comment: How can I enable `ForInStatement` and `ForOfStatement`?

Comment: @shinzou same as above except use `["error", "LabeledStatement", "WithStatement"]`

Answer (score 2):

Add the below lines of code to restrict this error in your application in .eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb-base', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  plugins: ['no-only-tests'],
  rules: {
    'no-only-tests/no-only-tests': 2,
    "no-restricted-syntax": ["error", "ForInStatement", "LabeledStatement", "WithStatement"]
  },
};
```